# C# Adding a value to a variable when clicking a button

Tags: c#

So, huh, I'm kinda new to programming in general and I have a questions that maybe you could help me out. I don't know if I did this right but hope you can give me a light here.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int tick;
    private int conta_jogadas;
    private string[,] grelha = new string[3,3];



    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void pos00_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tick == 0)
        {
            pos00_button.Text = "X";
            tick = 1;

        }
        else if (tick == 1)
        {
            pos00_button.Text = "O";
            tick = 0;
        }

        grelha[0, 0] = pos00_button.Text;
        conta_jogadas++;
    }
```

And to verify it I have:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (conta_jogadas == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Teste");
        }

    }
```

For the moment I just want my button to add 1 to my variable. If i click it 3 times, my conta_jogadas will be = 3. I think I was clear here, don't know what else I can add to help. Well, thanks in advance guys.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: What happens when you run your app?  Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (conta_jogadas == 1)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Teste");
    }

}
```

Will execute exactly once, when your form loads. At that time the variable `conta_jogadas` will have the value `0` (The default for an `int`) so you will not ever see your message box.

You could change this to a normal function that you call whenever you update `conta_jogadas` if you want to see the message box when the value becomes `1`

Comment: So how could I do this?

Answer (score 0):

> For the moment I just want my button to add 1 to my variable. If i click it 3 times, my conta_jogadas will be = 3.

Try this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int tick;
    private int conta_jogadas;
    private string[,] grelha = new string[3,3];

    public Form1()
    {
         InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (conta_jogadas == 1)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("Teste");
        }
    }

    private void pos00_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        conta_jogadas++;
        grelha[0, 0] = pos00_button.Text;
    }
}
```

Every time button: pos00 gets clicked, variable `conta_jogadas` gets 1 added to the current number.

Note: couldn't compile since, I don't have Visual Studio installed here...

Comment: Didn't work, I think it's because of the thing @Jamiec said. I'm new at stackoverflow so I really don't know if I answering you guys right.

Comment: @user3087430 When do you want to show the messagebox? Or better, what do you want to happen and when?